# Webstorm and Meteor - Run and Debug in Webstorm greyed out?

Tags: meteor, webstorm

When I follow [this video exactly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeqkGF3Z7rU), the debug and run buttons in the Webstorm toolbar are greyed out which means I can't use the new debug features of Webstorm 9 - does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong? I did the exact same setup on another Mac and it works fine. This Mac did run Webstorm EAP 9 but I deleted it and fresh installed 9.0.1.

Comment: please attach a screenshot of your Run/Debug Configurations dialog (Run/Edit Configurations). Seems you haven't created a configuration to run

Comment: Thanks for replying - here they are http://imgur.com/a/A38qM

Comment: Hi @lena, are you Elena Pogorelova form JetBrains? If so, thanks so much for your help here on StackOverflow, and it would help if you added some details to [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2274212/lena), so people learn about JetBrains.

Comment: yes, it's me. Will do:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a run configuration to get these buttons enabled. Your screenshot shows that no run configurations have beed added - you modified the default configuration instead of creating a new one. Default configuration is just a template for creating new configurations. To add configuration, open Run Configurations dialog, hit Alt+Ins (or press '+' button), select the desired configuration from the list